# Mysql - Select MAX days passed between two records that match some criteria

Tags: sql, mysql

Let's assume below table `orders_daily_data` in which we store number of orders made for a given product across the time:

```
ID ProductType      Orders     OrderDate    
1   sugar           5          2023-01-04   
2   flour           0          2023-01-04   
3   pepper          7          2023-01-04
4   sugar           1          2023-01-05
5   flour           32         2023-01-05
6   pepper          0          2023-01-05
7   sugar           null       2023-01-06
8   pepper          1          2023-01-06
9   flour           0          2023-01-07
10  flour           0          2023-01-10
11  sugar           1          2023-01-11
12  pepper          1          2023-01-19
13  flour           1          2023-01-19
```

I'd like to find out the maximum number of days between two points in time when  product was ordered.

Desired result based on above data set:

`sugar` was not ordered for a longest time between 2023-01-05 and 2023-01-11 => 6 days

`flour` was not ordered for a longest time between 2023-01-05 and 2023-01-19 => 14 days

`pepper` was not ordered for a longest time between 2023-01-06 and 2023-01-19 => 13 days

Notes:

- There may be gaps in this table, meaning products were not ordered during that time
- null is treated as 0

I've tried bunch of approaches with join & group by but nothing seem to work as I expect:

```
select MAX(DATEDIFF(higher.OrderDate, lower.OrderDate)) from
orders_daily_data higher join orders_daily_data lower
on higher.ProductType = lower.ProductType and lower.OrderDate < higher.OrderDate
where higher.Orders > 0 and lower.Orders > 0
group by lower.ProductType
```

I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: If you have MySQL 8.x you should be able to use the `LAG()` window function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ProductType, Max(Days) Days
FROM (
    select ProductType,
        datediff(OrderDate, lag(OrderDate) over (partition by ProductType order by OrderDate)) Days
    from orders_daily_data
    where coalesce(Orders,0) <> 0
) t
GROUP BY ProductType
```

> https://dbfiddle.uk/PoGPd_2I

Results:

| ProductType | Days |
| --- | --- |
| flour | 14 |
| pepper | 13 |
| sugar | 6 |

---

The JOIN approach in the original question was close, but you needed the join to match only the one most recent row for each source row, and the easiest way to do that is with a [LATERAL JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html). You could also find the date you need to subtract with a correlated subquery in the `SELECT` clause or by combining a JOIN and row_number() function to use results when the row_number() is 1 ...

... but the windowing function approach I demonstrated above is typically the fastest/most efficient method, and with the least code, too.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can approach this, among several, particularly if your MySql is < v8 is to use a correlated sub-query:

```
select ProductType, Max(days) Days
from (
  select ProductType, DateDiff(
    Orderdate, (
      select max(orderdate) from orders_daily_data d2 
      where d2.ProductType = d.producttype and d2.orderdate < d.orderdate and Orders > 0
      )
    ) days
  from orders_daily_data d
)t
group by ProductType
order by Days desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Going off of the answer by @Joel Coehoorn; if you don't have mysql 8, this is closer to the join example that the OP was attempting. I would recommend adding an index as well to speed things up, if possible.

Query added by request; it was in the dbfiddle and I neglected to add it here, I only had the results to the answer.

```
SELECT 
  t.ProductType, 
  MAX(t.OrderDate) AS LastOrderDate, 
  MAX(t2.OrderDate) AS PreviousOrderDate,
  DATEDIFF(MAX(t.OrderDate), MAX(t2.OrderDate)) AS Days
FROM orders_daily_data t
  LEFT JOIN orders_daily_data t2 ON t2.ProductType = t.ProductType AND t2.OrderDate = (
      SELECT MAX(OrderDate) 
      FROM orders_daily_data 
      WHERE ProductType = t.ProductType AND OrderDate < t.OrderDate AND Orders > 0
  )
WHERE t.Orders > 0
GROUP BY t.ProductType
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/lbDT8AjB

Results:

| ProductType | LastOrderDate | PreviousOrderDate | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sugar | 2023-01-11 00:00:00 | 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | 6 |
| pepper | 2023-01-19 00:00:00 | 2023-01-06 00:00:00 | 13 |
| flour | 2023-01-19 00:00:00 | 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | 14 |